# Need SQL query with where condition definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an Sql query in that i need to pass some conditions to datetime field to retrieve the values. For Eg: I need the customers transaction until 31/12/2013. But one condition if that customer have any one  Transactions in the year of 2014 until to till date also it should not display. So how to write the where condition for this?

```
select distinct T1.CardCode as Customer , T1.CardName as CustomerName
from OINV T3 inner join
     OCRD T1
     on T1.CardCode = T3.CardCode inner join
     OCPR T2
     on t1.CardCode = t2.CardCode    
 where E_MailL = '' and T1.CardType = 'C' and
       ValidFor = 'Y' and T3.DocDate = ?
```

Comment: What do you mean "in the year of 2014 until to till date?  The date you provide is earlier than 2014.

Comment: So if that customer have any records in the 2014 and 2015 and 2016 it should not display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want customers who *last* date is 2013-12-31 and haven't had a transaction since.  You can handle this with aggregation and a `HAVING` clause:

```
select T1.CardCode as Customer, T1.CardName as CustomerName
from OINV T3 inner join
     OCRD T1
     on T1.CardCode = T3.CardCode inner join
     OCPR T2
     on t1.CardCode = t2.CardCode     
where E_MailL = '' and T1.CardType = 'C' and
      ValidFor = 'Y' 
group by T1.CardCode as Customer, T1.CardName
having max(t3.DocDate) <= ?;
```

In any case, the same basic idea can basic be used for other date restrictions as well.